# CodeIgniter - problema base_url

Tags: php, codeigniter-3

Hace poco empecé a desarrollar una aplicación con el framework CodeIgniter y me tope con el siguiente problema. El método `base_url()` me devuelve algo que no es el path por defecto de mi aplicación y esto me ha traido ciertos problemas.
Lo que el método me devuelve es `http://::1/wokspace` cuando debería retornar `http://localhost:8080/wokspace`.

Archivo config.php `$config['base_url'] = ''`

Espero alguin pueda ayudarme a solucionar mi problema.

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://::1/ es un equivalente en IPv6 a lo que http://127.0.0.1/ es en IPv4

En las ultimas versiones de CI es mejor no dejar en blanco el base_url, lo mejor seria que le pongas el local host. En tu caso seria:

```
$config['base_url'] = 'http://localhost:8080/wokspace'
```

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu respuesta.

Comment: De nada. También hace poco que empecé a usar codeigniter y me sorprendio gratamente. Suerte en tu desarrollo